# Get-PfxCertificate: Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'C' does not exist

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-powershell, pfx

I am new to powershell. Writting code in azure cloud shell.
I want to get pfx certificate information using Get-PfxCertificate command. But its not taking any path, whether its blob path or local path.
Giving error :
for Local
Get-PfxCertificate: Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'C' does not exist.

for blob path
Get-PfxCertificate: Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'https' does not exist.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JnrPU.png)

Appreciated for the help.

Expecting to resolve file path issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Get-PfxCertificate: Cannot find drive. A drive with the name 'C' does not exist.

If you are trying to execute the `Get-PfxCertificate` command from `Azure CLI` but `C Drive` is not available in the cloud

To resolve the issue, kindly upload the same `certificate` to **Azure CLI** and provide the cloud path as shown below

```
Ex: "/home/sagnic/thhejademotest-hello-20230716.pfx"
```

After uploading the certificate to `Azure CLI`, use the `ls` command to check the `certificate` and the `pwd` command to verify the path.

[image]

```
Get-PfxCertificate -FilePath "/home/sagnic/thhejademotest-hello-20230716.pfx"
```

**Output:**

[image]

If you have 100s of certificates to process, kindly move all certificates to one folder and try to execute the below powershell code.

```
#Define the folder path containing the certificate files
$folderPath = "C:\Venkat\Docker\Certificates"

#Get the list of certificate files in the folder
$certificateFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $folderPath

#Loop through each certificate file
foreach ($certificateFile in $certificateFiles) {
   
        # Get the PFX certificate
        $pfxCertificate = Get-PfxCertificate -FilePath $certificateFile.FullName
        $pfxCertificate
        Write-Host "PFX Certificate Thumbprint: $($pfxCertificate.Thumbprint)"   
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: It seems that what you call "Azure CLI" refers to the Azure Cloud Shell.

Comment: Yes, C Drive is not available in Azure Cloud Shell.

Comment: @VenkatV Thanks. I tried with adding pfx file in Azure cloud shell, and then got result of get-pfxcertificate. but I have 100s of certificate to process, so manually adding in cloud shell, will not work. and https path is blob path where all the certificate kept. So if I get this blob path, then it will be great. Any suggestion if this can be possible?

Comment: @Chhaya, I just updated my answer as your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You have not included the specific command you are trying to use, however it seems to have any syntax error as it also complains about the "http" when using an URL.

Let´s say you are trying to import the filename.pfx file located in the C:\ folder of your Windows machine, so you would have to use one of the following commands:

Get-PfxCertificate -FilePath C:\filename.pfx

or

Get-PfxCertificate -FilePath "C:\filename.pfx"